# How to get value stored at a certain byte location from a SQlite 3 file.

Tags: shell, sqlite, scripting, hexdump

I have a SQlite 3 format file which can be found at :

http://expirebox.com/download/55d8c804cbd8c3debe6e5128f350cd64.html

When I open it using a SQlite viewer I can acess this information which I need which is under :

[image: trc_count (info I need)]

Can I extract this information using hexdump some how need to use this info in a shell script.

Please help.

Comment: Why would you use a hexdump when you can simply execute a query?

Comment: Thanks CL I found the solution, apparently I was using an older version of sqlite.

Comment: When I am trying to loop to get the query it gives an error :

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
 
    ls -lrt | grep -w  "458752" | awk '{print $9}' | sort -V > list

    for linename in cat list 
do 

    /d/home/alima0152/Desktop/sqlite3 $linename "select trace_count from volume"; >> trc_count 

    done 

    rm list`